# news: pagination doesn't work any longer (after update to realurl 2.0.15)

Tags: typo3, realurl, tx-news

I am sure that the news pagination worked with realurl version `2.0.14`

After update to `realurl` 2.0.15 it didn't work any longer.

my postvarsets:

```
'page' => array(
  array(
    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
  ),
),
```

Comment: solved. the reason is that i was logged in the backend. after log out it works.

Answer (score 2):

RealUrl 2.0.15 removed cHash Regeneration. Which is considered a security Risk. cHash regeneration means it would be possible to do a Denial Of Service by flooding the pageCache with endless versions of the same page.

but While this change is good from a Security point of view. It breaks some Pages. where the cHash was not Correctly set before.

most Affected are Paginations and Single views of various plugins.

see this realUrl issue, where the topic is discussed in more detail:

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/244

Comment: Is there a solution / workaround for this and can you add it to your answer?